# Return most frequent occurence(s)

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm using MS Access 2010.

If I have a table like this:

Table1:

```
FirstName         LastName

  Alex              AAA
  Max               AAA
  Stewie            BBB
  Barney            BBB
  John              AAA
```

What query could return the most frequent LastName and how many times it occurs?
In this case it should return:

```
AAA      3
```

But if a LastName is tied in frequency (occur the same amount of time) it should return both.

I searched the net and stackoverflow and although many questions are similar they either don't solve my problem or are for another dialect than SQL Server.

Thank you.

Comment: `SELECT LastName, COUNT(*) as Res GROUP BY LastName ORDER BY Res DESC LIMIT 1` is what comes to mind.

Comment: If you're using Access, why did you tag this with MySQl?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Top returns matches in MS Access:

```
SELECT TOP 1 * 
FROM (SELECT names.LastName, Count(names.LastName) AS CountOfLastName
      FROM [names]
      GROUP BY names.LastName) a
ORDER BY CountOfLastName Desc
```

So the above query will return more than one row when there is more than one row with the same frequency.

Comment: Thank you that worked like a charm!
Could you explain a bit more what SELECT TOP 1 * does?

Comment: `SELECT Top 1` selects the first value with matches from the ORDER BY. In this case the ORDER BY is the count of frequency, highest first (DESC), so the most frequent name with any matches. You can `SELECT Top <any number>`, or `Top <any percent>%`

Answer (score 1):

```
Select
   LastName,
   count (*) as HowManyTimes
from myTable
Group By LastName
Order By count(*)
```